# Can I launch an EC2 instance only when a web request is detected?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a web application that uses a lot of RAM, but it's only used a few hours per day. I would like to reduce the cost of having the Amazon EC2 instance up. Is it possible to have a cheap instance acting as a front-end (maybe nginx configured as reverse proxy) that can start the more expensive instance when it detects a web request, and shut it down after a period of inactivity?

The problem I can't seem to figure it would be how to keep the connection "on-hold" while the instance boots, and then forward it to the larger instance.

The questions are:

1. Is something like this possible?
2. What would be the best way to do it?
3. Would it be worth it?

Comment: What about the NginX Lua module? You could write a short Lua script that fires up the application if it isn't running and then sends an HTTP redirect back to the same location. Providing NginX is configured with a `try_files` directive that first attempts to connect the web app before going to lua, it should be viable.

Answer (score 0):

i think if you look how php/chat rooms work you should get some where 
if you have control over how the server is called eg. your own html or what ever way you use to call the server if not 
till an instance is up and running will take a few minutes any program (you dont have control over) will time out till then

other thing is how frequent you will access this instance
keep in mind you pay per hour 
so if you get a request start the instance serve the request shut the instance down 
and that 25 times a day you payng more then when it would have run nonstop all day